# How to set default font color in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

I want to set the default font colour for the flutter app globally. I tried

```
ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    fontFamily: 'Gilroy',
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      bodyText1: TextStyle(),
      bodyText2: TextStyle(),
    ).apply(
      bodyColor: const Color(0xff22215B),
      displayColor:  const Color(0xff22215B),
    ),
  ),
```

Some text is coloured. but Text in Appbar is not applied automatically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apply this

```
ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
                bodyColor: const Color(0xff22215B),
                displayColor: const Color(0xff22215B),
              ),
        ),
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
              bodyColor: const Color(0xff22215B),
              displayColor: const Color(0xff22215B),
            ),
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

`textTheme` alone does not affect AppBar. You should use `appBarTheme`. Try this:

```
appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
                    textTheme: TextTheme(
                      //...
                    ).apply(
                        bodyColor: Color(0xff22215B), displayColor: Color(0xff22215B))),
```

Answer (score 1):

Select your theme at https://rxlabz.github.io/panache_web/#/.

Download the total theme code as well from that website.

Sample Code default font color in flutter?

```
  final ThemeData myTheme = ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: Color( 0xff2196f3 ),
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      display4: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0x8a000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      display3: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0x8a000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      display2: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0x8a000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      display1: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0x8a000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      headline: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      title: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      subhead: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      body2: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      body1: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      caption: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0x8a000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      button: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      subtitle: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xff000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      overline: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xff000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
    ),
    primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
      display4: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xb3ffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      display3: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xb3ffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      display2: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xb3ffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      display1: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xb3ffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      headline: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      title: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      subhead: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      body2: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      body1: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      caption: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xb3ffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      button: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      subtitle: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      overline: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
}
```

Sample Code Full:

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  final ThemeData myTheme = ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: Color( 0xff2196f3 ),
    primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    primaryColorLight: Color( 0xffbbdefb ),
    primaryColorDark: Color( 0xff1976d2 ),
    accentColor: Color( 0xff2196f3 ),
    accentColorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    canvasColor: Color( 0xfffafafa ),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color( 0xfffafafa ),
    bottomAppBarColor: Color( 0xffffffff ),
    cardColor: Color( 0xffffffff ),
    dividerColor: Color( 0x1f000000 ),
    highlightColor: Color( 0x66bcbcbc ),
    splashColor: Color( 0x66c8c8c8 ),
    selectedRowColor: Color( 0xfff5f5f5 ),
    unselectedWidgetColor: Color( 0x8a000000 ),
    disabledColor: Color( 0x61000000 ),
    buttonColor: Color( 0xffe0e0e0 ),
    toggleableActiveColor: Color( 0xff1e88e5 ),
    secondaryHeaderColor: Color( 0xffe3f2fd ),
    textSelectionColor: Color( 0xff90caf9 ),
    cursorColor: Color( 0xff4285f4 ),
    textSelectionHandleColor: Color( 0xff64b5f6 ),
    backgroundColor: Color( 0xff90caf9 ),
    dialogBackgroundColor: Color( 0xffffffff ),
    indicatorColor: Color( 0xff2196f3 ),
    hintColor: Color( 0x8a000000 ),
    errorColor: Color( 0xffd32f2f ),
    buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
      textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.normal,
      minWidth: 88,
      height: 36,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:0,bottom:0,left:16, right:16),
      shape:     RoundedRectangleBorder(
      side: BorderSide(color: Color( 0xff000000 ), width: 0, style: BorderStyle.none, ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2.0)),
    )
 ,
      alignedDropdown: false ,
      buttonColor: Color( 0xffe0e0e0 ),
      disabledColor: Color( 0x61000000 ),
      highlightColor: Color( 0x29000000 ),
      splashColor: Color( 0x1f000000 ),
      focusColor: Color( 0x1f000000 ),
      hoverColor: Color( 0x0a000000 ),
      colorScheme: ColorScheme(
        primary: Color( 0xff2196f3 ),
        primaryVariant: Color( 0xff1976d2 ),
        secondary: Color( 0xff2196f3 ),
        secondaryVariant: Color( 0xff1976d2 ),
        surface: Color( 0xffffffff ),
        background: Color( 0xff90caf9 ),
        error: Color( 0xffd32f2f ),
        onPrimary: Color( 0xffffffff ),
        onSecondary: Color( 0xffffffff ),
        onSurface: Color( 0xff000000 ),
        onBackground: Color( 0xffffffff ),
        onError: Color( 0xffffffff ),
        brightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
    ),
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      display4: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0x8a000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      display3: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0x8a000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      display2: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0x8a000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      display1: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0x8a000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      headline: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      title: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      subhead: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      body2: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      body1: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      caption: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0x8a000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      button: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      subtitle: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xff000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      overline: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xff000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
    ),
    primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
      display4: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xb3ffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      display3: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xb3ffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      display2: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xb3ffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      display1: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xb3ffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      headline: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      title: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      subhead: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      body2: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      body1: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      caption: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xb3ffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      button: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      subtitle: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      overline: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
    ),
    accentTextTheme: TextTheme(
      display4: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xb3ffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      display3: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xb3ffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      display2: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xb3ffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      display1: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xb3ffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      headline: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      title: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      subhead: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      body2: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      body1: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      caption: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xb3ffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      button: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      subtitle: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      overline: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
    ),
    inputDecorationTheme:   InputDecorationTheme(
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
    helperStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
    errorStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
    errorMaxLines: null,
    hasFloatingPlaceholder: true,
    isDense: false,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top:12,bottom:12,left:0, right:0),
    isCollapsed : false,
    prefixStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
    suffixStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
    counterStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
    filled: false,
    fillColor: Color( 0x00000000 ),
    errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color( 0xff000000 ), width: 1, style: BorderStyle.solid, ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
    ),
    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color( 0xff000000 ), width: 1, style: BorderStyle.solid, ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
    ),
    focusedErrorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color( 0xff000000 ), width: 1, style: BorderStyle.solid, ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
    ),
    disabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color( 0xff000000 ), width: 1, style: BorderStyle.solid, ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
    ),
    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color( 0xff000000 ), width: 1, style: BorderStyle.solid, ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
    ),
    border: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color( 0xff000000 ), width: 1, style: BorderStyle.solid, ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
    ),
  ),
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(
      color: Color( 0xdd000000 ),
      opacity: 1,
      size: 24,
    ),
    primaryIconTheme: IconThemeData(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      opacity: 1,
      size: 24,
    ),
    accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      opacity: 1,
      size: 24,
    ),
    sliderTheme: SliderThemeData(
      activeTrackColor: null,
      inactiveTrackColor: null,
      disabledActiveTrackColor: null,
      disabledInactiveTrackColor: null,
      activeTickMarkColor: null,
      inactiveTickMarkColor: null,
      disabledActiveTickMarkColor: null,
      disabledInactiveTickMarkColor: null,
      thumbColor: null,
      disabledThumbColor: null,
      thumbShape: null(),
      overlayColor: null,
      valueIndicatorColor: null,
      valueIndicatorShape: null(),
      showValueIndicator: null,
      valueIndicatorTextStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
    ),
    tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
      labelColor: Color( 0xffffffff ),
      unselectedLabelColor: Color( 0xb2ffffff ),
    ),
    chipTheme: ChipThemeData(
      backgroundColor: Color( 0x1f000000 ),
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      deleteIconColor: Color( 0xde000000 ),
      disabledColor: Color( 0x0c000000 ),
      labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top:0,bottom:0,left:8, right:8),
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0xde000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:4,bottom:4,left:4, right:4),
      secondaryLabelStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Color( 0x3d000000 ),
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
      secondarySelectedColor: Color( 0x3d2196f3 ),
      selectedColor: Color( 0x3d000000 ),
      shape: StadiumBorder( side: BorderSide(color: Color( 0xff000000 ), width: 0, style: BorderStyle.none, ) ),
    ),
    dialogTheme: DialogTheme(
      shape:     RoundedRectangleBorder(
      side: BorderSide(color: Color( 0xff000000 ), width: 0, style: BorderStyle.none, ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0.0)),
    )

    ),
  );
```